# How can I remove columns with red heading in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have file with red heading, and i want to delete whole column using VBA code?
Can i use loop to find red heading and delete the column instead of Column Countrt??

Comment: yes, you can loop columns and compare their fillColor (or what is it exactly) and if its red delete whole column. But i think nobody cant help you more if you didnt provide more info

Comment: Just loop trough the heading and delete the red ones`If TargetRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then TargetRange.Delete End If`

Comment: Can you paste a screen capture so we can see how your sheet looks?

Comment: Can you help me writing complete code, Thanks

Comment: @SarithaMachadi Please check the edited answer.

Comment: I have got it..thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in the line `If Cells(1,ICntr). Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then` between `Cells(1,ICntr).` and `Font.ColorIndex` also change `Columns(ICntr).EntireColumn.Delete` to `Columns(ICntr).Delete`

************* EDIT ************:
Assuming that you have data/text in your headings (first cell of column) this macro will do the trick. Remember that when looping through ROWS or COLUMNS and deleting then, you should always REVERSE the loop to make sure all rows or columns were checked!

```
Sub DeleteColumnsWithRedHeader()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim i As Long

'Change to you sheet name!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Set ws = Sheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME")

'This will give you the last column index with data
lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loop through all column with data - REVERSE LOOP TO CHECK ALL COLUMNS
For i = lColumn To 1 Step -1

    'If first cell in column is RED then delete that column
    If ws.Cells(1, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then ws.Columns(i).Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, but a comment to a new question posted as an answer... phew.